# Android Google Search by uploading Image

Tags: java, android

I am developing Android Application, in my application user will take photo using the camera, that photo has to be uploaded to this url http://images.google.com/searchbyimage I want to know how to upload the file to this URL and how to parse the response and display the images in the Grid.

Comment: You may want to read this reference https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#request

Answer (score 0):

Google image search is based on meta data and actual file properties. So what you want to get done may not work as you wish to as it will be completely different image.

It might work only with landmarks, for example if you take photo of big ben and search picture on google that might find things related to Big Ben. Same with brands, if you take picture of Coke bottle that might work. But if you take picture of say somebody or some object that will not work I am afraid.

Comment: Questioner wants to find out how to use the search. This answer talks about potential search result considerations ... but does not help with "how to call".

Comment: I checked my photos with the google image search (through browser) it gave the result that I wanted now I want to implement it in Android